# Iterator not acting as expected

Tags: c++, iterator

Code:

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator first = iter;

if( ++iter != iter_is_pointing_to_this_vector.end())
{
  ...
```

When de-referencing the iterator "first" a Segmentation fault occures. When commenting out the de-referencing the program simply halts at the if statement and does not continue. The incrementing of iter obviously does not do what I expect: I want to make sure that the vector in question has or has not more members pass the item that "iter" is pointing to.

What is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: what is iter pointing to? please show complete code to reproduce this.

Comment: Could it be that `iter` is already at `end()` before the increment?

Comment: You probably intended `iter + 1`, but this still seems wrong.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve, but I am pretty sure that a vector `v` of type `std::vector<T>` does not have any members beyond `v.end()` by definition.

Comment: iter is pointing to a member of the vector iter_is_pointing_to_this_vector. All of this sits in a while loop: while(iter != iter_is_pointing_to_this_vector.end()) and iter gets incremented in the bottom of the loop as the last action done in this loop. If iter is pointing to the last element in this vector then I dont want to do anything, but if its not pointing to the last element then I have to take these elements after it and add them to a separate vector.

Comment: Ok. `vector.end()` is a pointer to the first element *past* the vector. So when `iter == vector.end()` is true, then (*iter) already results with undefined behaviour or crash. Also I am not sure what happens when you do ++iter on an iterator which already points to an end. Maybe even this is forbidden. I do not remember what documentation says about it :). It might be that when `iter == v.end()` then `++iter` will also lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: You are increasing the iterator "in the bottom of the while loop", but you're also increasing the iterator in that if-statement in your code snippet. That means the iterator gets incremented twice within the loop. Your while loop will not terminate, because the iterator will be beyond `end()` when you check for it in your while condition. As Pubby said, you probably meant `iter + 1`, not `++iter`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct! I thought that ++iter wont reassign iter.

Comment: Just a note on Pubby's and dhavennith's answers. `operator+` is implemented only for `RandomAccessIterator` which is the most specialized version. This can be done properly also for `BidirectionalIterator` and `ForwardIterator`. It might be a useful remark when you come across similar problem with other container or try to refactor working loop to a function that accepts iterators and decouples work from the container type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the comment got too long so I will post it as an answer however it might be not complete.

Construct such as `++iter` will advance an iterator. So if you have your line within the loop and another `++iter` at the end of it you will advance it two times per loop!. `++iter` does not yield an iterator that points to the next element, it rather moves the `iter` to it.

From what i understand you do `++iter != iter_is_pointing_to_this_vector.end()` to check if the next element is an end. To determine if the current element is the last one in vector. But the code you wrote does something different.

To perform what you want you would need another iterator, that you would set to the next element from the current one.

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator = iter = v.begin();
std::vector<std::string>::iterator = iter2 = v.begin();
++iter2;
while( {...} ){
  if(iter2 != v.end() ){...}
  ++iter2; ++iter;
}
```

Of course you need to make sure `v` has more than one element.
You could also use `reverse_iterator` if your container provides it.

```
typedef iter_t std::vector<std::string>::iterator;
iter_t = iter = v.begin();
std::reverse_iterator<iter_t> = iter2 = v.rbegin();
while( {...} ){
  if(iter != iter2.base() ){...}
  ++iter;
}
```

Note: `base()` converts reverse iterator to a normal (forward) one, so they can be compared.

Edit:
It seems that you can use `reverse_iterator` with the Bidirectional iterators, which mean they also would have implemented decrement operations. Therefor, since you do not really need to iterate in a reverse direction, just need an iterator to one element relative to the `end`, an easier way would be:

```
typedef iter_t std::vector<std::string>::iterator;
iter_t = iter = v.begin();
iter_t = iter2 = v.end();
--iter2;
while( {...} ){
  if(iter != iter2){...}
  ++iter;
}
```